# Full screen landing page: text exceeds div on small screens

Tags: responsive-design, fullscreen, center, font-size, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I need to make a classic full screen landing page with a h1 title, a h2 sub-title and a call-to-action button to slide the content to the first div of the website. I really hope you can help me because the website should go online soon and this is the one thing that's stopping me from saying it's finished, I'll try to tell you everything so you have a better understanding on what's going on.

> *Here's my Fiddle:* jsfiddle.net/daghene/szp7yf7h/1/
>
> And this is an online version of the real page with the first bit of
>   content below it http://andreacordioli.com/macwip2

I'm using Skeleton Framework and the div containing the fullscreen image is outside the .container who's wrapping the grid, while the h1, h2 and button are inside it. Right now I have two problems:

- for some reason, only in this part of the website, text bigger than a certain point exceeds the page width making the website scrollable horizontally under a certain point
- I made it so the text gets smaller under the 550px mark which is where the Skeleton grid comes into play. I tested it on my Motorola Moto X which has around 1280x720 resolution and noticed if I check the website in landscape it doesn't trigger the smaller resolution text propieties and the text exceeds the width of the windo again: this happens on iPhones in Chrome tester too

What I wonder right now is: as of today, **what's the best practise to make a 100% responsive landing page** with such simple content that is always centered, works on all possible resolutions and device orientations withou exceeding borders and has the text always at a decent size never being too big?

For instance, the text exceeding the width is 8rem which equals to 80px in Skeleton. Here's the page I'm trying to achieve, which I'll need to serve a different image for on mobile when aspect ratio is X:Y where Y gets bigger than X somehow:

[image]

If you try it it kinda works ***and I even tested it on my old, first Samsung Galaxy Tab*** which has the super old Android 2 or 3 browser which gives me more problems than IE but actually centers everything correctly with this code...but the main issue is that the text isn't scaling properly and if the window is too narrow it either disappears on the right, making the window scrollable on the right and part of the big title unreadable, or if it gets too small(say my 1280x720 4,7" Moto X) the call to action button disappears since the screen window is too short and there's the browser bar too. I put overflow: hidden to this windows to be sure there's no horizontal scroll but the real problem is not the scroll, it's the text exceeding the div instead of getting smaller.

**LAST NOTES!**

- If you check the css there's a "-1rem margin" on the H1 because as I
  said for some reason in this specific section the H1, and just that,
  doesn't center. The H2 and Button are centered, the H1 is not and
  only here...don't get why.
- If you try to make the window horizontally smaller you can see the text touches the window on the right side first(both in the Fiddle and in the other link where there's no html and body margins), still can't get why and I feel that's what's preventing the text to stay centered while getting smaller.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that some of the problems you describe are because at viewport 550px wide, your h1 font jumps in size from 5rem to 8rem. But at this viewport size there isn't enough horizontal space to hold your h1 text and so it exceeds the width of its parent div, and hence appears to be off-centre.

I think a solution would be to tweak your CSS in http://andreacordioli.com/macwip2/css/includes.css starting around line 1047 to something like the following:

```
@media (max-width: 625px) {
  .bigImage h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
  }
...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi David, thanks for replying! That's something I thought about but as you can see in the img below it appears that I still have something spacing content and making it exceed the border, note that in the picture the browser window is 340-360px which is higher than the iPhone 4 meaning it would get worse for iPhone 4 users.

I still don'tu understand if it's Skeleton making the test exceed the browser width or if it's something else. In case it's Skeleton wouldn't be easier to make its container start after this landing page and re-make it from scratch? !(http://i.imgur.com/NPfv4qA.png)

Comment: The screenshot was taken after I put this custom rule: 

    @media (max-width: 625px)
    .bigImage
  text-align: center
 .bigImage h1
  font-size: 2rem
 .bigImage h2
  font-size: 2rem
 .bigImage a
  font-size: 2rem

Comment: I noticed one more thing: if you remove everything inside .bigImage(meaning the whole section) and its relative css it seems there's still something that makes the content exceed the width so it's not the style of this section but something on a higher level, see the image http://i.imgur.com/cFuVK3g.png

Comment: You've raised a number of issues . To make it easier for me to troubleshoot, at what viewport width(s) are you seeing problems @daghene?

Comment: I had problems both on small screens and wider than taller viewports and that's why I re-inspected my code and found out that it was the combination of the text itself and the Skeleton spacing for it causing problems. If you paste in your browser "andreacordioli.com/macwip3" you should see the work in progress which should work perfectly on desktop, mobile and even smaller screens like iPhone 4's with custom media queries.

The button and text should also show down to 300px and a little bit smaller if you don't have tons of bars in your browser, tell me if that seems good to you :)

Comment: Looks like you may be working on your site at the moment, your demo link seems to be off-line. I'll check again later.

Comment: That's because I finished it and moved it to another sub-url, it's on "andreacordioli.com/macfinale" now :)